# How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities?

Tags: terminal, unix, utilities

I found there is some differences between the utility command I used on the mac OSX and linux. I want to make my experience united.

How could I replace all my mac utilities with GNU utilities?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71119/benefit-of-using-macports-coreutils-instead-of-stock-os-x.

Comment: Here's a guide https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: I sympathize with your frustrations but I believe that, in the long term, it will cause greater frustration if they are *replaced* - After seeking to do the same thing I'd recommend using `homebrew` as mentioned below, and then just learning to use the utilities with a `g` ( `gsed`, `greadlink`, etc ) instead of replacing the system utilities.

Comment: For grep, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx

Comment: I disagree with @cwd, using `--with-default-names` is only affects the local user. It could be an issue with mac oriented terminal utilities, but if you use homebrew for everything, you might aswell pretend you're using linux. Mixed with iterm2, it's working great for me, I can basically pretend I'm home with my linux boxes.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Is it possible to get the full suite of unix options for the command line tools on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90921/is-it-possible-to-get-the-full-suite-of-unix-options-for-the-command-line-tools)

Comment: NOTE: `cp` and `mv` might be dangerous to file’s extended attributes (e.g., tags, invisible, alias, bundle, and more).  For details, see these two articles:

http://brettterpstra.com/2014/07/03/mavericks-tags-and-coreutils-a-warning/

http://brettterpstra.com/2014/07/04/how-to-lose-your-tags/

They are a little dated, but I just want to raise the warning so you can investigate if using GNU’s `mv` and `cp` will interfere with your needs.

Comment: Does anyone have a concrete example demonstrating that this "will cause greater frustration"?

Comment: @cambunctious concrete example: a script that uses the default utility for your system will break.

Comment: @DeNovo that's not concrete

Comment: @boileau I'd say its concrete enough. Any installation script for a package that tries to use your default utilities based on your OS may fail or do strange things and cause strange errors. That would be quite painful I think. When it will happen who knows, but it is quite likely!

Comment: @CodeNovitiate sorry but saying "here is a vague category of things that might happen" is not concrete. Concrete would be a link to a script that fails and a description of how.

Comment: Yes, great question.  It is a pity.  After decades of using gnu untilities, these more classic shell commands just seem broken.  For example it seems absurd to have xargs without a -d flag.  It requires so many extra keystrokes just to deal with output from grep -l to update files.  And I have yet to figure out why sed -i -e ...  results in appending -e to all the filenames.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

This adds symlinks for GNU utilities with g prefix to `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
brew install coreutils findutils gnu-tar gnu-sed gawk gnutls gnu-indent gnu-getopt grep
```

See `brew search gnu` for other packages. If you want to use the commands without a g prefix add for example `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` before other directories on your `PATH`.

```
$ brew info coreutils
coreutils: stable 8.21
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils
Depends on: xz
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.20 (208 files, 9.4M)
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.21 (210 files, 9.6M) *
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/coreutils.rb
==> Caveats
All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.

If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Additionally, you can access their man pages with normal names if you add
the "gnuman" directory to your MANPATH from your bashrc as well:

    MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

Comment: FWIW, I have a Homebrew Formula that acts as a meta-package for all those great GNU utils: see `shiny-and-gnu.rb` in https://github.com/al-the-x/homebrew-mine/

Comment: The first PATH works, but MANPATH failed, why? Is it because I'm using OSX10.10? I echoed $MANPATH, and I got `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:`, seems original MANPATH wasn't include. After commented out the MANPATH conf in my bashrc, I got nothing by `ecoh $MANPATH`. And of course, if I use `man pwd`, I got the BSD manual. How to fix this?

Comment: For `findutils`, you need to add `PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/findutils/4.4.2/bin:$PATH"` which is not stated in the installation console output.

Comment: In addition, to get the right man page for `findutils`, add this to your `$MANPATH` `/usr/local/opt/findutils/share/man`

Comment: @Zen: the right way to initiate `MANPATH` so as to keep the default system value is: `MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:${MANPATH-/usr/share/man}"`. The key is in the construct `${var-default_value}`.

Comment: Is there a package available that installs all of these tools at once?

Comment: I'm running this to generate symlinks in my ~/bin directory:
`utilDir=coreutils/8.25; cp -a /usr/local/Cellar/${utilDir}/libexec/gnubin/* ~/bin` 
Just change the `utilDir` for each set of utilities you want to link. Then I can just set `PATH="/home/me/bin:$PATH" without making such a mess with different directories.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, it seems your snippet has some weird Unicode chars in it which show up when copy-pasting: https://i.imgur.com/qQWygg2.png

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat What's that for?

Comment: I don't remember. But I needed it for mine to work. I guess it would not use the GNU version of `find` or some other common program, which you can always tell when getting an error using `find` without a directory argument.

Comment: Setting `PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 66):

Besides `brew install coreutils`, you may also need to install some other packages, such as `gnu-sed`, `grep`:

```
brew install findutils
brew install gnu-indent
brew install gnu-sed
brew install gnutls
brew install grep
brew install gnu-tar
brew install gawk
```

Note that the `--with-default-names` option is [removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=default-names%20created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&unscoped_q=default-names%20created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&type=Commits) since January 2019, so each binary has to be added to the path if they are to be used without the `g` prefix.

Old reference (when `--with-default-names` was available): http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Note that `brew install gawk` (unlike all the others) will replace `awk` (via a symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/awk`). If you want to keep the original `/usr/bin/awk`, just `rm /usr/local/bin/awk`

Comment: Is there a GNU version of `ping` available?

Comment: @HappyFace I don't think so. On GNU/Linux, `ping` is a Linux kernel utility: https://github.com/iputils/iputils/

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure that I would recommend *replacing* them; however, you can install them to a different path and utilize them that way.  Overall, if you are coming from Linux and would like access to more "generic" *nix utilities, and a system similar to apt, then I would recommend looking into Macports:
http://www.macports.org

It allows, for example, using the latest "generic" GCC, as opposed to/in addition to Apple's included GCC, just as an example.

Comment: For instance, tar and zip from Mac OS X know about metadata that the GNU versions do not.

Comment: There are Apple supplied apps, which are just GUIs for some command line tools and if you replace them the apps may start behaving strangely, so go with adding, not replacing.

Comment: Right; something like Macports adds them, it doesn't replace them.

Comment: If you want to use the GNU utilities by default with MacPorts you can add `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin` to the front of your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 13):

I've written a script to do exactly this!  The script can be viewed [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/clayfreeman/2a5e54577bcc033e2f00/raw/gnuize.sh) (or below).  However, I can't always guarantee this post will reflect the latest version of the script linked previously.

Upon running the script, Homebrew will be installed (if not already), all the associated GNU utilities will be installed (if not already), and the `PATH` variable will be built from the installed utilities.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install Homebrew (if not already installed)
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL "\
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

# Install required packages from Homebrew
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install coreutils binutils diffutils ed findutils gawk gnu-indent gnu-sed \
  gnu-tar gnu-which gnutls grep gzip screen watch wdiff wget bash gdb gpatch \
  m4 make nano file-formula git less openssh python rsync svn unzip vim \
  --default-names --with-default-names --with-gettext --override-system-vi \
  --override-system-vim --custom-system-icons

# Empty the .bash_path file that holds GNU paths
[[ -f ~/.bash_path ]] && mv ~/.bash_path ~/.bash_path.orig

# Build PATH variable script in ~/.bash_path
for i in /usr/local/Cellar/*/*/bin; do
  echo 'export PATH="'$i':$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_path
done
for i in /usr/local/Cellar/*/*/libexec/gnubin; do
  echo 'export PATH="'$i':$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_path
done
for i in /usr/local/Cellar/*/*/share/man; do
  echo 'export MANPATH="'$i':$MANPATH"' >> ~/.bash_path
done
for i in /usr/local/Cellar/*/*/libexec/gnuman; do
  echo 'export MANPATH="'$i':$MANPATH"' >> ~/.bash_path
done

# Check if .bash_path is being called from .bash_profile
PATCH=`grep "~/.bash_path" ~/.bash_profile`
if [ "$PATCH" == "" ]; then
  # Add Ubuntu-style PS1 to .bash_profile
  cat <<EOF > ~/.bash_profile
export PS1="\[\033[1;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\]:\[\033[1;34m\]\w\[\033[0m\]# "
EOF
  # Add .bash_path to .bash_profile
  echo "source ~/.bash_path" >> ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Answer (score 12):

I have written a script that transparently transforms the macOS CLI into a fresh GNU/Linux CLI experience by

- installing missing GNU programs
- updating outdated GNU programs
- replacing pre-installed BSD programs with their preferred GNU implementation
- installing other programs common among popular GNU/Linux distributions

https://github.com/fabiomaia/linuxify

```
git clone https://github.com/fabiomaia/linuxify.git
cd linuxify/
./linuxify install
```

It also allows you to easily undo everything.

```
./linuxify uninstall
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to setting the PATH and MANPATH environment variables (which I would actually recommend), it is also possible to symlink binaries to an existing PATH location like this:

You need to know where Homebrew installs `coreutils` binaries.

```
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin
```

The [`/usr/local/opt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337601/why-is-there-a-usr-local-opt-directory-created-by-homebrew-and-should-i-use-it) directory is where Homebrew stores relatively static files that are unlikely to change between updates.

Then you can create symbolic links from there to a location that is already on your PATH. It must be a path that is loaded early on PATH, because the PATH is searched on a first-come, first-serve basis. `/usr/local/bin` is a good choice based on looking at `echo $PATH`.

```
which sha256sum # prove it is not on PATH
ln -s /usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin/sha256sum /usr/local/bin/
which sha256sum # prove it is on PATH
```

This way, it would *almost* as easy to create symbolic links. In some cases, like when you want tighter control, it is a good option rather than adding an entire directory to your PATH and MANPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using `brew install coreutils` to install the tools. But if you want to use them without the `g` prefix and are using [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), you can add `gnu-utils` to your zshrc file to do enable this easily:

```
plugins=(... gnu-utils)
```

More info available here: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/gnu-utils

Comment: How does this impact shell scripts expecting the BSD version of commands?

Comment: @nohillside The plugins should be set in your `.zshrc` file, so their effect should only apply to interactive shells rather than scripts.

Comment: the only problem I see with this is: what if you want to bring some user scripts that work in a GNU/Linux environment to macOS?