# Homebrew: Easy way to add 'gnubin' to path for multiple packages?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew

I would like to use Homebrew to install GNU versions of several utilities, and use the GNU versions by default with their usual names.

From the output of `brew install gnu-tar` and by reading [How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities) I learned that I can add `/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin` to my `$PATH` variable. However, for other packages, the `gnubin` directory is under a different path, like `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` for the `coreutils` package.

Do I have to add each of these to my path by hand, or does Homebrew provide an easy way to collect all of the entries in various `gnubin` directories into one place?

I suppose I could put some kind of auto-finding script in my `.bash_profile` like:

```
GNUBINS=$(find -L /usr/local/opt -type d -name gnubin | tr ' ' ':')
export PATH=$GNUBINS:$PATH
```

However this feels a little clunky and insecure, and I was hoping for a Homebrew-specific solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proposed `find` based solution takes about 5 seconds to execute on my system. The following bash snippet executes in a fraction of a second.

```bsh
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)
  # gnubin; gnuman
  for d in ${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/*/libexec/gnubin; do export PATH=$d:$PATH; done
  # I actually like that man grep gives the BSD grep man page
  #for d in ${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/*/libexec/gnuman; do export MANPATH=$d:$MANPATH; done
fi
```

Comment: Nice and fast! One caveat: if there are no such `gnubin`s it will put literally `/usr/local/opt/*/libexec/gnubin` on the path, but presumably one is only running this if one has at least one `gnubin` there. :) (and furthermore, my original `find` command suffers from a similar issue)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `homebrew/bin` directory?

I am using Boxen (including Homebrew) at work, Homebrew is installed to `/opt/boxen/homebrew`.

I have `/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin` directory with links to all the Homebrew utilities.

`coreutils` is a bunch of commands, not a single formula, so I think you still need to add it to your `PATH` but you should not have to do this for other GNU software like `gnu-sed`, `gawk` or `findutils` if you install them with `--default-names` option.

Here is a simple list of my `/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin`

```
[admin@nzx-mb-125:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin] : ls -l | grep -i awk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  staff   28 16 Dec 16:51 awk -> ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.0/bin/awk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  staff   29 16 Dec 16:51 gawk -> ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.0/bin/gawk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  staff   35 16 Dec 16:51 gawk-4.1.0 -> ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.0/bin/gawk-4.1.0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  staff   30 16 Dec 16:51 igawk -> ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.0/bin/igawk
[admin@nzx-mb-125:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin] : ls -l | grep -i sed
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  staff   31 16 Dec 16:52 sed -> ../Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2/bin/sed
```

Comment: thanks for the formatting tips, I will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: I do not appear to have `homebrew/bin`. I guess that would be specific to Boxen. If I find that I need to link a lot of GNU binaries, I'll consider giving Boxen a try.

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think there's any shortcuts provided by Homebrew. You have to prepend the directory into `PATH` manually.

```sh
function gnuon {
  local gnu_packages=(
    coreutils
    findutils
    grep
    gnu-sed
    gnu-tar
  )
  local i
  for i in ${gnu_packages[@]}; do
    if [[ -d "/usr/local/opt/${i}" ]]; then
      export PATH="/usr/local/opt/${i}/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
      export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/${i}/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
    fi
  done
}
gunon
```