# Can I use GNU ps on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line

We can [install GNU coreutils](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities) via `brew`. But [there's no `ps` in the utils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities). Can we use gnu `ps` in OS X?

I'd like to use GNU `ps` as it has more options and features.

Comment: have you tried running `ps` or `ps -ef` in a terminal on OSX? works for me on OSX 10.7.5 with no modifications, on two different machines. It's in /bin/ps

Comment: Yup, I know, I wanted to use GNU `ps` because it has more options and features.

Comment: ah OK, sorry I didn't realise that from the question as stated. I'd suggest including that somewhere, incase anyone else thinks the same as me - good luck with finding a solution

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added more explanation about that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no portable ps program. The ps command available on linux is, as others have mentioned, from the "procps" package. The reason why this cannot be ported to OSX is because Linux and OSX kernels do not expose this information in the same way. Linux uses a pseudo-filesystem in /proc, whereas OSX uses the sysctl function. Other systems may use either mechanism but provide data in a different format, or may require programs like ps to read directly from the kernel's memory.

In general there is no standard for how process information is available to programs like ps and top; so the program has to be designed for a specific operating system. If there is a specific feature missing from the OSX ps, you'll have to find another program that can do it, or write one yourself (look at the [sysctl manual, in particular KERN_PROC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) as a starting point), or modify [the existing ps command](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158/ps/) to add the feature.

Alternately, if you can get what you need by parsing the output of the ps command itself, you may be able to write a portable program - the output with the `-o` option is reasonably reliable across platforms, particularly if you [refer to the UNIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) for the column names to use.

Comment: Is the `/proc` filesystem the only method the Linux kernel provides for getting a list of processes, or are there also separate system calls which provide that information?

Comment: @TannerSwett I don't think so. Before /proc was implemented, the ps command on linux worked by reading from /dev/kmem and /dev/swap.

Answer (score 15):

No - since it does not exist. As to **why** there is no builtin `ps` in GNU’s `coreutils` package, see [this answer on the Unix & Linux Forums.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106848/67197)

The best alternative formula available via Homebrew is [`psgrep`](https://code.google.com/p/psgrep/):

> psgrep  is a small Bash shell script that searches the process list
>   (as obtained by **ps(1)** ) using the awesome utility **grep(1)**  for  its  power.

That said, you can still use `psgrep` to behave as OS X’s `ps` would. For example:

```
   OPTIONS
   -a     Search the process list using BSD's "ps aux" format. This option
          includes all users' processes in the search.

   -b     Search the process list using BSD's "ps  ux"  format  (default).
          This option only includes the running user's processes.
```

---

[`pgrep`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?pgrep%201) is also available via `brew`, which is syntactically closer to `ps`, but less efficient than `psgrep`:

> **psgrep(1)** is  more  useful  than **pgrep(1)** because not only can it search the process list and return a PID, it can give more useful information such as  its  UID,  GID,  memory/CPU usage, niceness, **and anything else supported by ps.**

---

All emphasis mine.

Comment: `pgrep` is part of recent versions of OS X as well

Comment: @patrix agh! good point, confirmed: `type -a pgrep`
`pgrep is /usr/local/bin/pgrep`
`pgrep is /usr/bin/pgrep`

Comment: Just as an aside, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225/278323), the `proctools` package from either MacPorts or Homebrew provides `pgrep` and `pkill` which is what I personally was looking for when I showed up here.

Answer (score 8):

`ps` is not part of GNU coreutils according to [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities).  The version that comes with my Linux distribution seems to be from [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/download.html), but it seems like there is no formula for it in homebrew.  There are formulas for `pstree` which can give you great tree views, and also `htop` is another good process viewer.