# How to get the basic linux ps functionality in mac?

Tags: command-line, unix

In linux the basic [`ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) command only shows very basic information about the processes running in the same terminal.

For example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sleep 100 &
[1] 4071
[root@localhost ~]# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4025 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4071 pts/2    00:00:00 sleep
 4078 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
[root@localhost ~]#
```

What is the way to achieve the same simple output in mac?

The ps without any options in mac, prints a lot more information than processes running in the same terminal.

---

Apparently there is [no ps port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187783/can-i-use-gnu-ps-on-os-x) from linux to mac for a good reason

---

About the ps that I have :
Running El Capitan 10.11.6

```
$ which -a ps
/bin/ps 



$ ps --version
ps: illegal option -- -
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
```

Some example output

```
$ /bin/ps | wc -l
          69

$ ps | grep iTerm
 2462 ttys000    0:00.20 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /usr/bin/login -fpl hbaba /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
 4157 ttys001    0:00.19 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /usr/bin/login -fpl hbaba /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
 4241 ttys002    0:00.20 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /usr/bin/login -fpl hbaba /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
 4296 ttys003    0:00.20 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /usr/bin/login -fpl hbaba /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
 4380 ttys004    0:00.20 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /usr/bin/login -fpl hbaba /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
 4456 ttys005    0:00.21 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /usr/bin/login -fpl hbaba /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I gather the concern is that the MacOS version of `ps` follows BSD conventions and displays all your processes associated with *any* controlling terminal. Linux `ps` follows System V/POSIX conventions and shows your processes on the *current* controlling terminal.

To replicate the POSIX behavior, just run `ps -T`.

Answer (score 2):

/bin/ps on macOS also provides the same style of output as your example for me.

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 22261
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
22124 ttys000    0:00.14 bash
22261 ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 100
$
```

Check if you have any aliases set up (run `\ps`) and make sure it's /bin/ps that you're running.