# How to install and use GNU Grep in macOS

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

I have coreutils but I am not sure if GNU grep is there. 
I just want to use the flag `-P` for Perl regex that is found in GNU grep, but not in BSD grep.

My PATH is `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/masi/.cabal/bin` so I have coreutils first in the PATH.

However, grep is BSD when I am using it: `grep --version` gives `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`.

Command `type -p grep` returns `/usr/bin/grep`

How can you install GNU Grep in macOS?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

GNU grep is not part of coreutils. To install, run

```
brew install grep
```

As with coreutils, this doesn't automatically replace the existing grep

```
==> Caveats
All commands have been installed with the prefix "g".
If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

So after installing you can either use `ggrep`, `gegrep` and `gfgrep`; or extend `PATH` as shown above to use `grep` etc. The second option may confuse some macOS specific scripts though in case the options differ.

Answer (score 14):

The answer from nohillside needs updating as follows:

If grep was already installed by brew, remove grep first.

```
% brew uninstall grep
```

Then install grep:

```
% brew install grep

All commands have been installed with the prefix "g".
If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
=º  /usr/local/Cellar/grep/3.3: 21 files, 880.7KB
```

Note that you do need to modify the PATH. For example, add to your .bashrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

I had to do the above on my mac when after `brew upgrade` my grep was no longer accessible (it was installed previously with `brew install grep --with-default-names`, and this option is not available any more).

This solution works as of Homebrew 2.1.1:

```
brew --version
Homebrew 2.1.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 5afdd; last commit 2019-04-22)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision a5a206; last commit 2019-04-22)
```

This answer is based on the one from nohillside, with comments from Jonathan Komar and scott m gardner.