# Perl RegEx in Mac terminal: grep -p "^([^\t]*\t){2}mypattern\t" textfile.txt doesn't work

Tags: perl

I am a beginner of using programming commands.

Why {2} is not functional after ([^\t]*\t) in macOS terminal?

Is there any website providing Perl RegEx which works in mac? Thanks!

Comment: `grep -p "^([^\t]*\t){2}mypattern\t" textfile.txt` does not return an error on macOS 10.12. Are you seeing an error message or is your regex not matching as you expect?

Answer (score 3):

`bsd grep` does not use perl regular expressions. Please read `man grep` and note what the `-p` option does. Again, `man 7 re_format` explains how regex works in macOS with tools such as `grep` and `sed`.

In your regular expression the character `\t` is not interpreted as the tab control character. So you will need to type the literal tab character ( control + v, tab ) instead -

```
grep -E '^([^   ]*      ){2}mypattern ' FILE
```

or you can use ansi-c quoting (Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.) -

```
grep -E $'^([^\t]*\t){2}mypattern\t' FILE
```

You can also use `perl` directly -

```
perl -ne  'print if /^([^\t]*\t){2}mypattern\t/' FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

RegExPlanet offer a [Regular Expression Test Page for Perl](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html). This page works with Safari on macOS 10.12.

You may find that `grep` included with macOS does not include all the functionality you want. If so, try [installing `grep` from Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288) or MacPorts.