# How to install GNU base64 on Mac OS X?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, unix

I'm trying to run linux scripts on the mac, but even brew's updated base64 doesn't support `-w0`. I want something close to `base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.22`

Instead of `base64 1.5` from brew or the unknown version MacOs ships with whose binary's md5 is 718fe34e4012999c180f807fe323e7f1

I've had great luck by using iTerm and loading .bashrc to replace most bsd/mac utilities with gnu ones.

P.S. There is little reason to install the one from brew, as it line breaks by default and has no way to disable that "feature".

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/69223/34417

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4558#issuecomment-408225004

Brew does have the gnu version in the `coreutils` package. It installs it as `gbase64`

Answer (score 0):

*(I don't have the points to add a simple comment to @ray-foss answer)*

Given that my PATH has `/opt/homebrew/bin`, I symlinked over the brew base64, so both are available, in case the other might be needed, if ever.

```
brew install coreutils
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/gbase64 /opt/homebrew/bin/base64
```