# Is it possible to fix the spacing when using "ls" with colored output?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

This is the exact same issue found here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165154/changing-the-spacing-between-files-in-ls

When you run the command `ls -G` or `CLICOLOR=1; ls` the spacing in the output gets squished.

These images demonstrate what's going on (taken from the old thread):

Running `ls` when `CLICOLOR` is unset or set to 0:
[image: <code>ls</code> when <code>CLICOLOR</code> is unset or set to 0]

Running `ls -G`:
[image: <code>ls -G</code>]

This happens in any terminal emulator (terminal.app, iterm, kitty) and any shell (bash, zsh).

As the commenter points out in the previous thread, this is caused by `ls -G` setting `f_notabs=1`. From the source file https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-242/ls/ls.c.auto.html:

```
    if (f_color) {
        /*
         * We can't put tabs and color sequences together:
         * column number will be incremented incorrectly
         * for "stty oxtabs" mode.
         */
        f_notabs = 1;
        ...
```

Is there any way to fix this? I can't find any information on this since 2014.

Obviously this isn't the end of the world, but `ls` is one of the most frequently called shell commands and being able to have both color and nice spacing makes things easier to read. I am surprised there seems to be very little written about this as I would expect it to impact a large number of people.

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you expect here. If it‘s a problem coming from the way `ls` is coded a bug report for Apple might give better results.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Terminal or iTerm you can go to preferences and look for option to change fonts. For iTerm its shown in the image below.

[image]

If you click on the change font button you get the following pane.

[image]

As you can see in this image there are sliders to adjust the character spacing. you can spread the characters out on the iTerm windows.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that option exists in the terminal menu, but it doesn't have anything to do with the issue I'm suggesting. All that does is increase the width of each cell in the terminal. It does not change in any way how many whitespace characters are printed.


On the other hand, the issue I had is with the number of whitespace characters printed. Specifically, when you run `ls -G` it outputs fewer whitespace characters than `ls` because it changes tabs to a single space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different program.

One comment on your linked question suggests using [homebrew to install GNU Coreutils](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities).  Alternatively you could simply download it from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/), unzip it and can compile it with:

```
cd ~/Downloads/coreutils-8.31
./configure
make
```

You then get a version of `ls` that formats output for color and monochrome the same.  If output will fit on one line with two spaces between names it prints it irrespective of color setting.

[image: ls wide output]

The macOS version (in color mode) conversely works out the longest name and pads the others to be the same length (plus one) which is why I have one space after *Documents* and five after *Music*. This does look a bit messy but you'd have to alter the program to change this behavior.

This is seen more clearly here:

[image: ls - different length file names]

Note that if the window is too narrow to fit the information on one line then both wrap:

[image: ls narrow output]

The main issue with replacing the program is the macOS [ls](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html) and GNU [ls](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) don't have the same options.  For example `-G` on macOS version means *"Enable color output"* while on GNU version it means *"in a long listing, don't print group names"*

Whether getting consistent layout for color and monochrome in exchange for different options is a matter of opinion.